# How can I increase the maximum stack size of notifications in the notification tray?

Tags: samsung, notifications, push-notifications

So my current phone is a Samsung Galaxy S21. I receive a LOT of push notifications, by choice. The problem is, when I receive those push notifications for, say, Twitter, the number of notifications that are displayed in a single "stack" in the notification tray CANNOT exceed 24; once the stack reaches 24 notifications, I do not receive any further push notifications for that app. This is a HUGE issue when I'm trying to keep track of a big Twitter thread or watch for an important email. My previous phone, a Galaxy S8, had a maximum notification stack size of 40, after which the same issue occurred; this leads me to believe that there is some variable SOMEWHERE that can be changed to increase or decrease the stack size.

Just to clarify, since Google brought up similar questions but no relevant answers:

- I am **not** referring to the notification *badge* displayed on the app icon on my home screen; I am referring to the notifications *in the notification tray* viewable by swiping down from the top of the screen. Image attached to show what I am talking about.[image: My notification tray, showing a stack of Twitter notifications; the notification count is at 9.]
- This issue is not app-specific; all apps seem to have a stack size of 24, whether it's Twitter, Gmail, YouTube, a game, or whatever. Each app DOES have its own stack, but each of those stacks can only go up to 24 notifications.

I have checked every setting I could access on my phone; none of them changed anything relevant. If there is ANY way to change the stack size, even if I have to manually dump my phone's kernel to my PC and use a hex editor to change the relevant bytes, I will do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

There is no option is on any phone that allows you to do that, sorry.